# Using Mobile local storage as database in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

When building a mobile app using MeteorJS and MongoDB as database, we know that mongodb has to be placed in a server pointing to your meteor app for it to work.

Is it possible to create a mobile app in Meteor wherein it will create a collection locally using the storage of the mobile device? If so may I know what package it is?

I tried using "ground:db" but I do not know how it works. Is it the right package to my approach?

I tried the codes found on the link:

https://atmospherejs.com/ground/db

Somehow the code `var list = new Ground.Collection('list');` does not work the same way as `var list = new Meteor.Collection('list');` . . You can not do `list.find().fetch()` with Ground.Collection.

Comment: I think you are asking for some reference of the code. I would like you to place a code here what you have tried. It will be helpful. Instead of asking for tool, you can update the question with a code in it.

Comment: @JafferWilson - I have added info, I hope it helps

Comment: I would suspect your using two different library's that have different API's that's why `list.find().fetch()` exists in one but not the other.

Comment: @ste2425 - I see, but I am testing it with a clean from the scratch meteor project which only contains ground:db as added package and nothing more.